# Show ImageView programmatically

Tags: android, android-imageview

How can I make an ImageView appear in the middle of the screen when the user clicks a button? I have placed the image in the res/drawable-folder.

I've been trying with the code below but I don't know how to make the ImageView appear:

```
 View v = new ImageView(getBaseContext());
 ImageView image; 
 image = new ImageView(v.getContext()); 
 image.setImageDrawable(v.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.gameover));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -15, accepted):

- Create the [ImageView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)
- Use an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) in the button
- [Add](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView%28android.view.View%29) the ImageView to the layout or [set the visibility](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) of the ImageView to VISIBLE

Comment: not very helpful. should have stated "check the documentation"

Comment: Too vague... "1) Learn java 2)read android documentation" might work as well.

Comment: WOw, harsh. I thought his answer was well written and used appropriate links to answer the question.

Comment: @FuriousFolder Answer the question with code, not links.

Comment: @FuriousFolder this is stack overflow not link overflow  :)

Answer (score 136):

```
//LinearLayOut Setup
LinearLayout linearLayout= new LinearLayout(this);
linearLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

linearLayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

//ImageView Setup
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);

//setting image resource
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);

//setting image position
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

//adding view to layout
linearLayout.addView(imageView);
//make visible to program
setContentView(linearLayout);
```

Answer (score 29):

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("gameover", "drawable", getPackageName());
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams vp = 
    new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
imageView.setLayoutParams(vp);        
imageView.setImageResource(id);        
someLinearLayout.addView(imageView);
```

Answer (score 8):

If you add to **RelativeLayout**, don't forget to set imageView's position. For instance:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(200, 200);
lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT); // A position in layout.
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this); // initialize ImageView
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
// imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.photo);
RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.addView(imageView);
```