# Dynamic image view

Tags: java, android

I have an app where some buttons spawn different images. Each time one of the buttons is pressed, the imageView created should have an unique name.

My idea is to add a variable to the name of the imageView, like "ImageView+i", where "i" increments each time the button is pressed, and more imageViews with different names start to appear. I know it is not possible in this way, but it is with a Map.

Any ideas of how to implement this with Map?

Comment: Why don't you use an `ArrayList<ImageView>`?

Comment: That may work, but is there a way to set an imageView while the code is running, without adding it to the XML?

Comment: Yep. You can do it all programmatically http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180802/android-imageview-programmatically