# TableLayout inside HorizontalScrollView adds padding when multiple rows are added to the Table

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have a TableLayout inside a HorizontalScrollView. When I add a single row of images, the images are side by side, no extra padding.

But when I add another row, and the images scale down, the TableLayout creates extra padding horizontally around each cell, but not vertically.
Here is my code:

```
    TableLayout grid = (TableLayout) deckBuilder.findViewById(R.id.grid);

    for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j) {
        TableRow testRow = new TableRow(this);
        \\Each row has the same weight
        testRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 1f));
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i) {
            ImageView testImage = new ImageView(this);
            testImage.setImageResource(R.test_image);
            testRow.addView(testImage);
        }
        grid.addView(testRow);
    }
```

And here is my xml:

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/horizontalscroll"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dip" 
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:overScrollMode="never">

       <TableLayout 
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >
       </TableLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

Sorry mis-read the code.

Solution:

set the width/height of your image views to wrap_content.  You do this via the

LayoutParams object:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams.html

See this question for an example:

[Show ImageView programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180802/android-imageview-programmatically)

```
//ImageView Setup
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
//setting image resource
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
//setting image position
imageView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Look at the docs here:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html

Specifically look at scaleType:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

I think one of the options there should resolve this (maybe...fitXY?)

Comment: I tried all of the scaling types, they either didn't remove the padding, didn't maintain aspect ratio, or cropped part of the image out.

Comment: Try setting layout_height to wrap_content perhaps?  I think your issue is that the views are not the same size as the images, and because of this scaling has to occur.  It's possible that uneven scaling is causing there to not be a "correct" way for the behavior you desire to occur.

Comment: Are your images perfect squares?  Or are they taller than they are wide?

Comment: They are taller than they are wide, but that shouldn't matter, since the TableLayout is inside a HorizontalScrollView, and the table is wider than the screen.

Comment: It wouldn't matter if they were in a vertical scroll view - because they're taller than they are wide, presumably they are being scaled to all fit within the screen height which is available.  They're being scaled to fit within the view size available to them. The views are probably the right size, but to scale the height correctly the width of the picture can't match the width of the view.  Make sense?

Comment: That would be why the pictures were cropped and the aspect ratio was weird when you used the scale_type method, because in order to fill a square view, a non square image is going to deform somehow.

Comment: It just doesn't make sense to me that the view can't adjust its width then.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43618/discussion-between-nathaniel-waggoner-and-s-l)