# How to add an ImageView to an empty layout using java in android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imageview

I have been figuring out a lot of sites and a lot of topics in stackoverflow too for the above mentioned question . But I am not able to arrive at a solution . So please help me out with this problem . I am trying to a add **ImageView** to an empty layout which has **RelativeLayout** as it's parent layout using **JAVA**. Please get me a solution . Thanks in advance

Comment: Which all questions did you look into?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180802/android-imageview-programmatically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout);

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 
                        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
         params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
        relativeLayout.addView(imageView, params);
    }
}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

1. Set an id to your layout.
2. Fetch your layout with `findViewById`
3. Create a new `ImageView`
4. Add the `ImageView` to your layout

Example:

```
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_layout_id);
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
layout.addView(imageView);
```

Note: I used LinearLayout since you only said that the parent layout is RelativeLayout, but forgot to mention the type of your *empty layout*.

Comment: It works fine for linear layout. But its not working for RelativeLayout

Comment: @c0deBeastx you mean you have a `RelativeLayout` inside a `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: Nope only one RelativeLayout . That is created by default when creating a xml file in Layout folder

Answer (score 1):

It would be easiest to add the imageView to your layout XML file, rather than starting with a blank line. So your layout XML file might look something like:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".[YOURACTIVITYNAME">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it from Java, you could put in code like this, just about anywhere in your Activity.  In the `onCreate` method for example, after you have inflated your layout.

```
ViewGroup yourEmptyLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.whatever_your_layout_ID_is);

ImageView myImageView = new ImageView(this);

// Add the new ImageView to the layout
yourEmptyLayout.addView(myImageView);


// You should also give your ImageView a picture to draw.
myImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

// or
// myImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```