# Android - Listview with variant number of images

Tags: android, image, listview, layout

I want to make a layout what looks like this:

[image]

Basically it's a `ListView`, on the left side there is only one picture, and the problem is how can/should I do the right side, where there can be one or more pictures?

```
<ListView>
    <LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal">
         <ImageView/>

         <??????>
    </LinearLayout>
</ListView>
```

Comment: You could add the Imageview programatically: here is an   example 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6180802/android-imageview-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the requested `ImageView`s dynamically in your program using [`ViewGroup.addView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#addView(android.view.View)). Layout XMLs can only describe static layouts.

Comment: Thanks! But...I added 5 ImageViews to the layout, but I see only 2 pictures, I think the other 3 are outside of the screen?...
How should I parameter the images, to "start a new line" if they would go outside of the screen?

Comment: Positioning is what the layout does, the images just draw in a space allocated for them. `LinearLayout` just places one after another in the direction you set. I don't think there is a layout that can do what you want but you can definitely write your own. Or you can use [`GridLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html) if all the image views have the same dimensions.