# (Android) Programatically Created ImageView Doesn't Add to LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I've tried to add a specific ImageView that I created in Java, to an identified LinearLayout which is always in the xml but starts out empty (I'm supposed to add and remove ImageViews to and from it constantly, but that doesn't work either. A few months ago it did work but i went on hiatus and when i came back it stopped working). Here's the code:

Main Activity (where the Layout is and ImageView should be - this is part of the OnCreate function):

```
ImageView iv=new ImageView(this);
iv.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(160,160));
Integer imgResId=R.drawable.dragon;
iv.setImageResource(imgResId);
iv.setOnClickListener(this);
iv.setId(0);
LinearLayout layout0=findViewById(R.id.firstHand);
if (layout0!=null)
    layout0.addView(iv);
```

xml LinearLayout part (there's supposed to be two different "hands" (layouts) in a single scrollview but right now I'm focusing on the first layout - 'firstHand'. I tried deleting the second layout but it doesn't make a difference):

```
<ScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstHand"
        android:layout_width="420dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
        <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstQueenHand"
        android:layout_width="420dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

*the 'dragon' picture in the drawable is fully loadable and didn't disappear or something.

When I run the program the Layout is empty... bare in mind that this used to work, I was able to add and remove ImageViews from the Hands (linearLayouts) and 'queenHand's (the other linearLayouts) and the game worked... I have no clue what changed as the app itself didnt load for a long time and when I finally fixed that error, the ImageViews stopped appearing.

any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12784207/8133524 hope helpful for you

Comment: `if (layout0!=null)` Is that null?

Comment: layout isn't null, continues into the condition and supposedly adds the iv to the view

Comment: I had just noticed that all the views aren't updating when i try to do so via the Java script. this includes TextViews etc. is there a deeper problem?